# Colouring individual isosurfaces in VMD outside the predefined colours

Tags: tcl, vmd

How can I colour multiple isosurfaces different colours in a TCL VMD script without having to use the predefined colours (e.g. iceblue, lime, mauve etc...)? Ideally this would involve using RGB colours and cannot involve changing the definition of the predefined colours.

Comment: It looks quite difficult to do; you apparently have to work with [coloring methods](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.7.1/ug/node74.html). You _might_ be able to use the ColorID index and then change the meaning of that index, but that might be what you're explicitly trying not to do.

Comment: Sorry yes, his isn't quite what I want. I have tried doing this already. However, the ColorID index is quite limited, and changes what the colours are globally. E.g. if I change the ColorID for 1 then it changes all red colours in my visualisation. Obviously for the lesser used colours like 'yellow3' this isn't a problem but if one requires more than 32 colours in the visualisation this method (from my understanding) can't be used.